# Hibernate read and update large data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to read large data from a table and update this.

What best solution for this?.

I using stream but it has issue

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@3ea407e4 is still active.`

No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called `.close()` on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
My code is  below:

```
Stream<UserNotificationDTO> dtoStream = userNotificationRepo.fetchAllUnreadByUserId(userId);
        dtoStream.forEach(userNotifyDTO -> {
            userNotifyDTO.setOpened(true);
            userNotificationRepo.save(userNotifyDTO);
        });
```

Comment: Performance wise, it's better to do with a single query, ex: `update notify set opened = true where user = :userId`

Comment: it is just sample for update large data. some functions nead more complex process before update.

Answer (score 0):

It can be one of two things:

1. You didn't close stream or result set
2. Problem with version of com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver you use

Comment: i try to close stream but it same error, jdbc version is     compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'

Answer (score 0):

It is a mysql limitation. You cannot issue other queries while iterating through the result:

> When using large result sets with MySQL there are a number of documented limitations... The net effect of these limitations is that you will have to read all of the rows of a result set (or close the connection) before you can issue any other queries on the connection, or an exception will be thrown

Source: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/dbsupport_mysql.html

Comment: in spring jpa, can i get new EntityManager with new connection ?.(spring using shared EntityManager) I think separate connection can resolve this issue.

Comment: @defimatech instead of patching a bad designed database, I advise you to migrate to a better one, ex: postgres. Later you can find other problems or limitations...